# Listview still reports a selectedItem after SelectedItems.clear

Tags: windows, vb.net, listview

Some words about my Visual Basic application.  It reads a family tree and amongst other things allows to draw graphics of a person to selected persons of his ancestors.  So, on the main screen I select for example myself and request a graphic from me to an ancestor.  My code for the "Stamlijn" form searches for my ancestors, and lists the oldest for each line in a listview.  For example 50 persons might get listed. From this list my code selects the oldest person in the parental line (this might be Carolus Buelens) and its selection makes my code draw the graph (later on the end-user might select another of my ancestors to draw another descendants line).  [A screenshot is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fBUHIGvtoXKuG-goEfZa9_41JzF9Axh8/view?usp=sharing).
Now, I return to my main screen and select my wife, and again I request for a graph.  And exactly like for my graph my "Stamlijn" class searches for her ancestors (16), and places them in an array of listview items, ready to execute an `AddRange`.  Here's the original code

```
   lvwMain.SelectedItems.Clear() : lvwMain.Items.Clear() 
   lvwMain.Items.AddRange(lvis)
```

But the listview start to act strange.  Right after the `SelectedItems.Clear`, and `Items.clear`, my lvwMain listview still thinks to have a selected item, the one of the previous run: Carolus Buelens.  **How's that possible** no item, but a selected item?
You also see the AddRange for the new items, with my wife's ancestors.  One of them has `Selected` set to True, the one for Antonius Hermans.  But, even after the `Addrange`, the Listview simply ignores that and `lvwMain.SelectedItems(0)` still is that of Carolus Buelens.  Needless to say the remainder of my code to draw a graph of the selected person to my wife fails as there is no link from him to my wife.
I also have some [screenshots from Visual Studio](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eTQ25tGLBhY8jcEm28EbjR1RCExVEJNa/view?usp=sharing) to illustrate what I find unbelievable.  They are taken right after both `clear()` calls.  Note that the code has been changed a bit during my debugging, the code during the screenshots:

```
      lvwMain.SelectedItems.Clear() : lvwMain.Items.Clear() : lvwMain.Refresh()
      Dim t As String = If(lvwMain.SelectedItems.Count > 0, lvwMain.SelectedItems(0).Text & _
                           lvwMain.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text & _
                           lvwMain.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text, "")
      lvwMain.SelectedIndices.Clear()
      lvwMain.Items.AddRange(lvis)
```

If I kill the Stamlijn class before requesting the graph of my wife, it goes fine [as can be seen here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nXIj1bCjYQFd2zEf8owtWR6m2Ie6yjSq/view?usp=sharing)

I must also admit that after I execute this new `SelectedIndices.Clear()` the old selected item is gone, but setting a new item to selected still fails.
And, I coded a bypass to no longer base the creation of the first graph on `lvwMain.SelectedItems(0)` (because that doesn't get set), but by passing global variables.

And, why do I still ask this question then?  Well, with my bypass, this listview still acts strange later on.  I won't enter all the details yet, maybe if one can shed a light on the first problem, I'll understand my current issue: same listview, same cleanup, but later I need to insert extra listview items somewhere in the middle (one can see them on the screenshots of me and my wife: persons colored pale yellowish). What I see for example: my array with listview items has 9 entries.  I did add them all at once with the `Addrange` shown above.  A while later (still before the screen is shown to the end-user) I want to insert extra people.  The graph is a bit different from mine or my wife's.  At that time `lvwMain.items.count = 9` but except for the first two items the others all are "nothing".  My code needs to test them to see where to insert (what obviously fails), but if I skip that part of the code, and insert the new persons simply at the end, the form gets displayed and the 7 items that were "nothing" before, display nicely, content as expected.  And this problem is much harder for me to bypass.

I'd suppose the Selected items to be empty after listview.selectedItems.Clear

Comment: I would have thought that only `lvwMain.Items.Clear() ` is necessary to clear all the collections.

Comment: Indeed, that's how my other VB applications work.  But, for one listview in an application I also had problems (many years ago) and I learned that it is wise to execute a `SelectedItems.Clear()` before `Items.Clear()`.  Then too I encountered the issue of still having a selected item in a listview without items.  Since then I always code both.